# How to write a text mode gui in Linux?

Tags: c, ruby, linux, bash, go

When I write scripts/programs, often I would like to pop up a simple text 'gui' to prompt for input:

[image: debian install screen]

How would I do this? For example from Shell, Ruby, Golang or C. I don't even know what this is called and Google isn't reponding to "text thingy from scripts".

(The example is from the Debian installer).

Comment: This looks like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). Check out https://github.com/ruby/curses

Comment: As Stefan mentioned, this is ncurses. There's also CDK which comes with some predefined widgets (check it out at http://invisible-island.net/cdk/). CDK is built on top of ncurses.

Comment: Actually, it's dialog.

Comment: @Fang This dialog was made with a higher-level toolkit but I forgot its name.

Comment: I wasn't aware of "Dialog". Learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, that is not [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html), but the newt library (there are a few differences in appearance).  It is used by [anaconda](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda) on Red Hat systems.  The whiptail program uses the library, however it has no real relationship to anaconda.

Anaconda is mostly in Python; it uses the newt shared library (written in C) from a Python binding.

For learning it... documentation is largely non-existent.  You have the source code.

Further reading:

- [screenshots for **dialog**](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog-figures.html)
- [newt.git](https://git.fedorahosted.org/git/newt)
- [anaconda.git](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda)
- [Any examples/documentation for python-newt](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/any-examples-documentation-for-python-newt.718922/) (discussion of newt vs documentation)
- [Spicing up the Console for Fun and Profit, Part 2](http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2011/11/spicing-up-console-for-fun-profit-2/)

Comment: Eh, I think it's allowed to mention that you're the maintainer of dialog, making this answer rather authoritative.

Comment: I suppose so, but the point is to provide information and show where the reader can learn more.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I notice there's a Golang newt library at https://github.com/aklyachkin/go-newt which should make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that there's no documentation.

Answer (score 4):

In the past this was known as "Dialog," though as Thomas points out (as the maintainer of Dialog!!) this is no longer the case.  This is most likely the Newt library.  While you could certainly write something lower level using ncurses, Newt is available in Linux pretty much universally.  Dialog can also be installed under Linux.  You can read some basic documentation for it [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php).

Choosing to use this over a curses based approach allows you to focus on what it is you're actually looking to do rather than doing all of the work to build a UI.  If, however, you are really looking to build UI elements, [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/) would be the way to go.